# Subir documento excel con Ajax y PHP

Tags: php, ajax

Tengo el siguiente codigo para subir un archivo excel al servidor

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST"><input id="file_presupuesto" type="file"></form>

var inputFileImage = document.getElementById("file_presupuesto")[0];
        var file = inputFileImage.files[0];
        var data = new FormData();
        data.append('excel',file);

    var url = "../ejemplo_excel/excel_capturar_presupuesto.php";
    $.ajax({
        url:url,
        type:'POST',
        contentType:false,
        data:data,
        processData:false,
        cache:false,
        success: function(respuesta){
            alert(respuesta);
        },error: function(){// will fire when timeout is reached

        }, timeout: 15000 // sets timeout to 3 seconds
    });

<?php

    echo basename($_FILES["excel"]["name"]);
```

El problema es que esto no esta funcionando obviamente la intención principal es subir el documento al servidor pero nisiquiera me imprime el nombre del archivo.

Necesito ayuda para poder subir esto al servidor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En la parte de ajax necesitamos veficar que no pase 4MB u 8MB, depende del servidor, puedes verificar que se envia en el modo desarrollador del navegador

**HTML**

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="formulario">
    <input id="file_presupuesto" type="file">
    <input value="Enviar" type="submit">
</form>
```

**Ajax**

```
$(document).on("submit","#formulario",function(e){
    e.preventDefault();//detemos el formluario
});
    var fo = ($("#file_presupuesto"))[0].files[0];  
    var yy = fo.size > 4000000;
    if (yy) {
        alert("Imagen a subir maximo 4mb");
        return;
    }
    var data = new FormData();
    data.append("archivo", fo);
    $.ajax({
        url: "../ejemplo_excel/excel_capturar_presupuesto.php",
        type: "post",
        data: data,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        error: function (e) {
            alert("Hubo error");
        },
        success: function (res) {
            alert(res);
        }
    });
```

**PHP**

para lo cual creamos una carpeta `archivos` al costado de `"excel_capturar_presupuesto.php"` ya depende de ti jugar con las rutas

```
$nombre = $_FILES['archivo']['name'];
$tipo = $_FILES['archivo']['type'];
$tamanio = $_FILES['archivo']['size'];
$ruta = $_FILES['archivo']['tmp_name'];
fulldest = "archivo/".$nombre;
// "archivo"
move_uploaded_file($ruta, $fulldest)
```